# how do I get my while statement to execute properly in C#?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to create a program by the name of "Count Vowels" that accepts a phrase from a user and outputs the number of vowels within that phrase.

I used a while statement with a nested if statement that runs through all the vowels, and counts the vowels, so that it can be displayed. When ever I run the program it is not going through my while statement and checking the vowels as intended. Instead it just keeps adding one to my count variable after each iteration.

I am new to C# and tried to understand the issue logically, but am having trouble trying to get my program to execute. If someone could please help me understand what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it. Below is the code that I am using.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
class CountVowels
{
   static void Main()
   {
      string phrase;     
      int count=0;
      int i=0;
     
      Console.WriteLine("please enter a phrase of your choice");
      phrase=Console.ReadLine();

      while(i < phrase.Length)
      {
         if(phrase[i]=='a' ||
            phrase[i]=='A' ||
            phrase[i]=='e' ||
            phrase[i]=='E' ||
            phrase[i]=='i' ||
            phrase[i]=='I' ||
            phrase[i]=='o' ||
            phrase[i]=='O' ||
            phrase[i]=='u' ||
            phrase[i]=='U')
            {  
               count++;
            }
         {
            i++;
         }    
         Console.WriteLine("The number of vowels in your phrase is {0}",count);
      
         Console.ReadLine();
      }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Which of these `}` close the while statement? I'm not sure if your code in your IDE is formatted the same here but if you indent on a {  and unindent  on a } you should be able to find why you're getting the wrong behavior.

Comment: `var count = input.Count(x => "aeiou".Contains(char.ToLower(x)));`

Comment: Just built this in a new console app and it found 4 vowels in "alakazam". It's not a build error or runtime error, what phrase(s) is it struggling with / what are your test results?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out with the code I had. It was simply because i needed to enclose my while statement and then take out the extra } at the end of my code.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop is overkill for this but I am assuming you have a requirement for this? How about a little refactor to clean it up? You will need LINQ for this example.

```
        using System.Linq;

        string phrase;     
        int count=0;
        int i=0;

        Console.WriteLine("please enter a phrase of your choice");
        phrase=Console.ReadLine();

        while(i < phrase.Length)
        {
            string[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};

            var characterValue = phrase[i].ToString().ToLower();

            if(vowels.Contains(characterValue))
            {  
                count++;
            }
            i++;
        }



        Console.WriteLine("The number of vowels in your phrase is {0}",count);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Or mush shorter still using LINQ but no loop:

```
        using System.Linq;

        Console.WriteLine("please enter a phrase of your choice");
        var phrase=Console.ReadLine();

        var count = phrase.Count(x => "aeiou".Contains(char.ToLower(x)));

        Console.WriteLine("The number of vowels in your phrase is {0}",count);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you for the other examples. It was a requirement to include the while statement and I was able to figure out the reason it wasn't working was because I did not enclose my while statement properly. Thank you for showing me other ways of handling it. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixing your problem**

```
var phrase = "asd";
var vowels = "aeiou";

int i = 0, count = 0;
while (i < phrase.Length)
{
   if (vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(phrase[i])))
      count++;
   i++;
}
```

**for loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++)
   if (vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(phrase[i])))
      count++;
```

**foreach**

```
foreach (var c in phrase)
   if (vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(c)))
      count++;
```

**foreach C#9 pattern matching**

```
foreach (var c in phrase.ToLower())
   if (c is 'a' or 'e' or 'o' or 'u')
      count++;
```

**Linq 1**

```
count = phrase.Count(c => vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(c)));
```

**Linq 2**

```
count = phrase.ToLower().Count(c => vowels.Contains(c));
```

**Regex**

```
var count = Regex.Matches(phrase, "[aeiou]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
```

**Efficient with a hashset**

```
var hash = new HashSet<char>("aeiou".ToCharArray());
var count = phrase.ToLower().Count(x => hash.Contains(x));
```

Note this is not really an answer, it was more showing option.

Comment: thank you for showing me more options. I was able to figure out the reason it would not work was because i did not properly enclose my while statement. I also had to take out the extra closing bracket at the end of my program.